# Confusion about poles and analytical functions

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to find the order of the pole at $z=0$ of the function $f(z)=\frac{\sin z}{z^5}$.

We know that the power series of $\sin z$ is

$$\sin z=z-\frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^5}{5!}-\frac{z^7}{7!}+\ldots$$

Then we have

$$\frac{\sin z}{z^5}=\frac{1}{z^4}-\frac{1}{3!z^2}+\frac{1}{5!}-\frac{z^2}{7!}+\ldots$$

We also know that the order of the pole $m$ is the smallest positive integer such that $g(z)=z^mf(z)$ is analytic.

If we multiply $f(z)$ by $z^4$ we have

$$\frac{\sin z}{z}=1-\frac{z^2}{3!}+\frac{z^4}{5!}-\frac{z^6}{7!}+\ldots.$$

If we see to the power expansion above we easily see that $\frac{\sin z}{z}$ is analytic, which is not true because $\frac{\sin z}{z}$ is not even defined at $z=0$.

I'm a little confused.

Comment: Your equation is only true if $z\neq0$. Thus $\frac{\sin z}{z}\neq 1-\frac{z^2}{3!}+\cdots$, for at least one $z$ value.

Comment: $\frac{\sin z}{z}$ has a removable singularity at $0$. Removable singularities are often tacitly considered removed, unless one is discussing isolated singularities, so one customarily says that $\frac{\sin z}{z}$ is an entire function.

Comment: Or one calls the function $sinc(z)$ and declares victory.